# How to Detect ios device using jQuery/JavaScript and hide Bootstrap modal only iPhone and iPad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, bootstrap-modal

Here I attach my jQuery code:

```
$('.myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () { 
var width = $(window).width(); 
var testdevice = /iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()); 
if(!testdevice) { $(this).css('display','block !important'); $(this).show(); } 
else{ $(this).css('display','none !important'); $(this).modal('toggle'); } 
});
```

---

Here is media query:

```
@media(max-width: 360px){
    .myModal{
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to provide more details of how the code is running - browser or app, what errors you are getting etc

Comment: I got this error during run time.
jquery.1.11.1.js?v=7.7:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(^|\.)bs\.(?:.*\.|)modal(\.|$)/: Stack overflow
    at RegExp.exec (<anonymous>)
    at RegExp.test (native)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch

Comment: It's a good idea to edit your question to make it more complete. You don't have the same formatting options in comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Detect iOS devices like:

var iOS will be true or false

```
var iOS = ['iPad', 'iPhone', 'iPod'].indexOf(navigator.platform) >= 0;
if (iOS)
{
//Hide modal 
}
else{
//show modal or do nothing
}
```